# Invert axis direction Altair

Tags: python, axis, altair

For some reason, the Y-axis while plotting with altair seems to be inverted (would expect values to go from lower (bottom) to higher (top) of the plot). Also, I would like to be able to change the ticks frequency. With older versions I could use `ticks=n_ticks` but it seems now this argument can take only boolean.

```
import altair as alt
alt.renderers.enable('notebook')

eff_metals =  pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name='summary_eff_metals')
points = alt.Chart(eff_metals, height=250, width=400).mark_circle().encode(
    x=alt.X('Temperature:Q',axis=alt.Axis(title='Temperature (°C)'),
            scale=alt.Scale(zero=False, padding=50)),
    y=alt.Y('Efficiency:N',axis=alt.Axis(title='Efficiency (%)'),
            scale=alt.Scale(zero=False, padding=1)),
    color=alt.Color('Element:N'),
)
text = points.mark_text(align='right', dx=0, dy=-5).encode(
    text='Element:N'
)
chart = alt.layer(points, text, data=eff_metals, 
                  width=600, height=300)
chart
```

And the figure:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I don't have your data, so difficult to write working code.

But here's an example of an inverted scale with additional ticks that is similar to the [example scatter with tooltips](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/scatter_tooltips.html) example.  See [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/vega-lite/robinl/9e9f8f950b82268a1a11ba85b20f5be0/cbd6ee0617c74aa02b23180dd82c1e523d84726a/scatter_with_invert_ticks.json) for it in the vega editor.

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
    
iris = data.iris()
    
alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalWidth',
    y=alt.Y('petalLength', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[7,0]), axis=alt.Axis(tickCount=100)),
    color='species'
).interactive()
```

This might work with your data:

```py
eff_metals =  pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name='summary_eff_metals')
points = alt.Chart(eff_metals, height=250, width=400).mark_circle().encode(
    x=alt.X('Temperature:Q',axis=alt.Axis(title='Temperature (°C)'),
            scale=alt.Scale(zero=False, padding=50)),
    y=alt.Y('Efficiency:N',axis=alt.Axis(title='Efficiency (%)'),
            scale=alt.Scale(zero=False, padding=1, domain=[17,1])),
    color=alt.Color('Element:N'),
)
text = points.mark_text(align='right', dx=0, dy=-5).encode(
    text='Element:N'
)
chart = alt.layer(points, text, data=eff_metals, 
                  width=600, height=300)
chart
```

However, I think it's possible that you've might just have the wrong [type](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/type.html) on your efficiency variable.  You could try and replace `'Efficiency:N'` with `'Efficiency:Q' and that might do it?

Comment: Oppsss, you were right. I had the wrong type for the efficiency variable. Thanks!

Comment: 404 at https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/simple_scatter.html

Answer (score 4):

While it's possible to reverse the `domain` manually, that requires hardcoding the bounds.

Instead we can just pass [`Scale(reverse=True)`](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.Scale.html) to the axis encoding, e.g.:

```py
from vega_datasets import data

alt.Chart(data.wheat().head()).mark_bar().encode(
    x='wheat:Q',
    y=alt.Y('year:O', scale=alt.Scale(reverse=True)),
)
```

Here it's been passed to `alt.Y`, so the years are inverted (left) vs the default `y='year:O'` (right):

[image: inverted vs default y-axis]